# Extension property delegated to instance property

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have the following class:

```kotlin
data class StuffWithParams<T>(
    val value: T,
    val params: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
)
```

You can then [delegate additional properties to the map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) like this:

```kotlin
data class StuffWithParams<T>(/* */) {
    val name by params;
}
```

---

Now, I would like to add extension properties to *typed instances* of this class, like this:

```kotlin
val StuffWithParams<Car>.speed: Int by params
```

This results in an error saying `Unresolved reference: params`.

```kotlin
val StuffWithParams<Car>.speed: Int by this.params
```

This, in turn, results in an error saying `'this' is not defined in this context`.

---

You can somehow get "around" this limitation by turning this into a getter property:

```kotlin
val StuffWithParams<Car>.speed: Long get() { val speed: Long by params; return speed }
```

...but it's ugly and increases the amount of boilerplate needed.

Is this intended? Is this a bug in the way `this` is resolved in case of extension property delegates?

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how delegated properties are translated [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#translation-rules-for-delegated-properties), and try apply it to your situation.

The translation rules would produce a new property storing the `params` map:

```
private val speed$delegate = params
var StuffWithParams<Car>.speed: Int
    get() = speed$delegate.getValue(this, this::speed)
```

But `params` can't be resolved, because there is no `this` in the initialiser of `speed$delegate`!

See also [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6643/this-is-unresolved-in-extension-property) on YouTrack.

The compiler could theoretically have implemented the translations rules to also translate the delegate property into an extension:

```
private val StuffWithParams<Car>.speed$delegate get() = params
```

But note that this is now a getter that returns `this.params`. If `params` were reassigned (though that will not happen in your case), the value of `speed$delegate` will also change. This could be very confusing because regular property delegates do not behave like this - they store the delegate instance in a different backing field.

You can "encapsulate" this "delegate using the `params` map" idea into a property delegate specifically for `StuffWithParamsDelegate`:

```
object StuffWithParamsDelegate {
    operator fun <T, U> getValue(thisRef: StuffWithParams<T>, property: KProperty<*>): U 
        = thisRef.params.getValue(thisRef, property)

    // optionally, declare setValue as well
}
```

```
val StuffWithParams<Car>.speed: Int by StuffWithParamsDelegate
```

Or more generally:

```
class MapDelegate<T>(
    // use a mutable map and add setValue if you like
    val mapProperty: KProperty1<T, Map<String, Any>>
) {
    operator fun <U> getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>): U 
        = mapProperty.get(thisRef).getValue(thisRef, property)
}
```

```
val StuffWithParams<Car>.speed: Int by MapDelegate(StuffWithParams<Car>::params)
```

Comment: This is an excellent and comprehensive answer. Much appreciated, especially after spending a considerable amount of time trying to find the best way to do it!